# Positive definiteness of product of symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A,B$ are symmetric and positive definite (real) matrices such that $AB$ is not symmetric (equivalently $AB\neq BA$). My question is, what are sufficient and/or necessary conditions for $AB$ being positive definite in this case?

For clarification, I call a square matrix $C$ 'positive definite' if $x^TCx>0$ for any vector $x$, regardless of whether $C$ is symmetric or not.

Comment: $C$ may not be symmetric, but only its symmetric part contributes to the quadratic form. The skew-symmetric part contributes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=AB$ and $D=\frac{C+C^T}{2}$. Even though $C$ is not symmetric, $D$ is. Moreover, $x^TCx=x^TDx$. So a sufficient condition for $C$ to be positive definite is that $x^TDx>0$ for all nonzero $x$, i.e., that $D$ is positive definite. One sufficient condition for the latter is that all eigenvalues of $D$ are positive. (This answer does not use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive definite.)

Comment: all of the leading principal minors of the matrix $D$ must be positive not only $\det(D)$ (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: @MisterDa You're right. That $\det(D)>0$ is only a necessary condition. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: you are welcome :)